# Count elements of in a multiple nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict

```
dt = {'condition': ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount'],
 'expand': ['expanduser', 'expandvars'],
 'get': ['getatime', 'getctime', 'getmtime', 'getsize']}
```

to count its elements.
I define a function

```
def count_nested_list(dt):
    i = 0
    for value in dt.values():
        for j in value:
            i += 1
    return i
```

alternatively can use `len(dt(0) + len(dt1) + len(dt2)`

How to solve the problem in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sum(len(v) for v in dt.values())
```